# Facebook OpenID vs Google OpenId

Tags: openid

What's the difference between Facebook OpenId provider and the other most famous such as google?

Comment: What is your question? OpenID is OpenID in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook is not an Open Id Provider They use their own OpenID-like system called Facebook connect
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Google Is also not Open ID provider.Google Use Federated Login for Google Account Users is based on OpenID Recomendations
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

OpenId is an Open Id providers
http://openid.net/